# What is the maximum amount RAM supported in the Lenovo H430?

Tags: memory, motherboard

I have a Lenovo H430 with the following specs:

- CPU: Core i5-3330 @ 3.0 GHz
- RAM: 8GB DDR3 @ 1600 MHz
- GPU: Intel HD 2500
- MB: Lenovo "Mahobay"

I have seen some reports of an 8GB maximum and some of a 16GB maximum from the reseller from who I bought the H430.

How much RAM is supported in the Lenovo H430?

Comment: -1 because you could just have looked it up in the bloody manual. Or googled it. It downloaded a manual if you misplaced it. And given the 3 upvotes on Keltari's answer I suspect I am just the vocal one explaining the -3 and the +3.

Comment: [SU] frowns on "Here, let me google that for you" answers, but the first hit I got on the query "lenovo h430 manual" yielded the [Hardware Maintenance Manual - Lenovo H4 Series ](https://download.lenovo.com/consumer/desktop_pub/lenovo_h4_hmm.pdf) and the [user guide](https://download.lenovo.com/consumer/desktop_pub/lenovo_h4_series_ug_v4.0_aug_2012_english.pdf). Both of these are way to generic and useless, but there **are** manuals.

Answer (score 5):

A simple search would reveal a maximum capacity of 8GB of RAM.

Answer (score 2):

The manufacturer tells you a maximum at the time the machine comes out, i have a 430 with 2 8gb ddr1600 chips in it and it works fine. Memory capacity is dependent on chipset and processor. the i5 can handle 32gb of ram but the h61 chipset wont let me go that high. Manufacturers want you to think that your machine is maxed out on memory, sounds good to a prospective customer. "oh max memory you say? I'll buy it"(consumer logic)... any ways good luck

Comment: thank you, finally someone who actually freaking knows what they're talking about